# How to save user inputs and retrieve back in a listview?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-edittext, favorites

I'd like to save the user inputs(string type) in `EditText` when "Add to favourites" button is clicked. And want to show the saved inputs in a `ListView` when the user chooses the "Favorites" tab. I have four tabs generally. I want to save the inputs in one tab, not in Favorites tab. How can I do this? I'm using eclipse. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use `SharedPreferences` to save and retrieve small chunks of data, for big ones consider saving it to a file

Answer (score 1):

Well you can always make an SQLite database and in one tab do the INSERT operation and in favorites tab do the SELECT from the db.

If you don't need that info to be saved in the database, you can make super-global variables, for example.
You can do that by making a new class called 'Constants', for example, and inside declare public static variables.
That way, they can be accessed from anywhere inside your app